# Finding Computer Name - Filtering for Name and Operating System

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter for Name and Operating system.

I can do name or operating system. But I cannot do both.

How do I get this working

```
Get-Content "C:\test.txt" | foreach {((Get-ADComputer $_ -Server:"Server 123"-Properties name,operatingsystem).name)}

Get-Content "C:\test.txt" | foreach {((Get-ADComputer $_ -Server:"Server 123"-Properties name,operatingsystem).operating system)}
```

Both work above.

```
Get-Content "C:\test.txt" | foreach {((Get-ADComputer $_ -Server:"Server 123"-Properties name,operatingsystem).name.operating system)}
```

Error

Comment: You may want to look at operators `-and` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/04/14/active-directory-powershell-advanced-filter-part-ii/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) to select the properties you need.

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity $ComputerName -Properties Name, OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property Name, OperatingSystem
```